# Codeigniter Route Not Validated

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm having some trouble in validating my website.

I am using a framework of `Codeigniter`. I tried to validate my website using this link
https://validator.w3.org/nu/ but it always an IO error and then I try to remove all my files and I just put some simple html in my index file and it works. Meaning I have some trouble in my `Codeigniter`.
Any suggestion will do the help thank you.

Comment: Was your site actually working before you tried running the validator?

Comment: No it didn't work. I just try to remove my codeigniter file and put some basic html code and it works fine so i guess the problem is all about codeigniter

Comment: did you have this site running under localhost?

Comment: No check [link](http://www.buyflygo.com).

Comment: by the way thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to validate server-side script which cannot be validated by [W3 validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). So either you need to host your project and provide address for validation or you can simply validate the views(front-end stuff) in the website. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i already have a provider address so it is not a problem anymore my problem is the route of codeigniter which is not validating everytime i use w3 validation.

Comment: I dont understand how you can attempt to validate a site using that service if the site itself isn't working. It's not Codeigniters fault, but we could raise an eyebrow towards those involved who are using it in this case :) I hear sounds of gooses making loud noises as they are being chased.

Comment: Have you tried visiting [link](http://www.buyflygo.com)? Its working fine